# Is there anyway to use a regex grouping in a static directory url handler in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, url

I've tried to get something like this to work in the app.yaml file:

```
- url: /([^\\]+)/static
  static_dir: /apps/\1/static
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `static_dir` must be a fixed prefix.

However, you could instead use [`static_files`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Pattern_Handlers), which utilizes regex groups.